# Spherical Trig: Finding A Missing Angle w/ The Sine Law

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I've been working on these spherical trig questions that I initially thought were rather straightforward. Instead, my attempts to finish this assignment have descended into madness because I cannot--for the life of me--figure out where I'm going wrong.

**Problem:** I'm given three subtending angles a = 37◦15′, b = 29◦51′, c = 20◦49′, and one interior angle C = 34◦37' of a spherical triangle; 
I am asked to find the remaining interior angles A and B using the spherical sine law.

**Attempt:** I know that the interior angles A + B + C must be greater than/equal to 180 degrees. 
From the spherical law of sines: sin(A)/sin(a) = sin(B)/sin(b) = sin(C)/sin(c). 
Thus, after converting from DMS to decimal degrees: 
sin(A)/sin(37.25◦) = sin(B)/sin(29.85◦) = sin(34.617◦)/sin(20.817◦)

Splitting these into 2 equalities, I solved for A and B and found: 
A = 75.371◦ and B = 52.715◦ 
By observation, A + B + C < 180◦, which is not possible for a spherical triangle.

I have reworked this problem several times, both in radians and degrees, and I can never get it. I am either making a careless error, or deeply misunderstanding spherical trig; either way, I would really appreciate it if someone could clear this up please. Cheers!

Comment: what is the source for the problem?

Comment: @WillJagy it is taken from a set of practice problems transcribed by my professor; he likely wrote it himself. our only instruction is to "determine missing angles in sides of the following spherical triangles," specifically using the sine formula.

Comment: What is the $15\prime$ representing? Does it represent the angle or the side measure?

Comment: @TobyHarnish the sides of the triangle are determined by the subtended angles at the origin, which are originally given in degrees, minutes, seconds. so 15' just represents 15 minutes, which I convert to decimal degrees later in my attempt (e.g. 37+(15/60) degrees).

Comment: there is also a law of Cosines  in the spherical case, you can find out what  angle $C$  should have been;  then you can find angles $A,B$  from the law of Sines,

Comment: Using the law of cosine $\cos c = \cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b \cos C$, I got a [slightly larger interior angle $C=35.81^\circ$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arccos%28%28cos%2820º49%27%29+-+cos%2837º15%27%29+cos%2829º51%27%29%29%2F%28sin%2837º15%27%29+sin%2829º51%27%29%29%29) (and both $A$ and $B$ should also be larger).

Comment: I assume you first calculated values for $\sin A, \ \sin B$ then applied arcsine. There are two values of an angle with a given arcsine, the sum of them being 180. most calculators return only the smaller of these; I don't know whether that is the problem...

Comment: unambiguous with all three angles by cosines, decimal angles $35.81^\circ, \; \; \; 55.03^\circ, \; \; \; 94.77^\circ \;\; . \; \; \; $  Sum $185.61^\circ$  but would come out below $180^\circ$  if the big one were replaced by supplement $85.23^\circ$